# XCode 5 build without developer account

Tags: ios7, xcode5, code-signing, jailbreak, ipa

Now that the JB for IOS7, and appsync also released, I would "only" need to build an IPA to test my software on my device.
-Fake code signing tutorials made for xcode 5 don't work with xcode 4
-I can't seem to make an unsigned IPA (afaik, this would also be installable with appsync on the device)

*some users marked a similar question a duplicate, but it wasn't that at all! Because he also tried to figure this out for xcode 5, and the "original thread" is from 2012 (xcode 4 era) and he (in the "original") didn't want to JB his device, so different story*

Answer (score 0):

fake code signing (the xcode 4 method) does work when I have appsync on my phone :)